# Why does Ruby's IO buffer behave differently when being sent to the terminal versus to another process?

Tags: ruby, io, terminal, buffer, stdout

If I ask Ruby to write to the terminal every 0.01s, it prints every 0.01s.

```
ruby -e "loop { sleep 0.01; puts Time.now }"
```

However, if I ask it to write to `tee` every 0.01s, it prints only once it has buffered (about every 5s, after 8196 characters).

```
ruby -e "loop { sleep 0.01; puts Time.now }" | tee
```

I can force it to print every 0.01s by setting `sync = true`.

```
ruby -e "STDOUT.sync = true; loop { sleep 0.01; puts Time.now }" | tee
```

For contrast, the same program written in bash does not appear to be buffered on its way to `tee` and prints to the terminal each 0.01s.

```
bash -c "while true; do date; sleep 0.01; done" | tee
```

Why does Ruby's IO behave differently depending on whether it's headed to the terminal versus being sent to another process first?

Comment: I think it is not Ruby but it is the piping mechanism in shell that is behaving differently. Ruby is running on the shell, and the shell can intercept it in the way it wants.

Comment: @sawa I had that hypothesis and tried to test it by running the bash program above. Is there a better way to distinguish between the two possibilities?